# How to get several rows from csv file with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to copy/paste csv files from one directory to another, to name the first column, and to get only 3 rows of the whole file, and the whole this to be run every 24 hours.

I have already done the first two points copy/paste from one directory to another and name the first column but I struggle to complete the third part. I need only 3 rows of the whole file.

Here it is some code for what I've done so far:

```
$Src = 'C:\1From'
$Dst = 'C:\2To'
$header = ‘Scan’

# Wildcard for filter
$Extension = '*_ALL_Scan_Details.csv'

# Get file objects recursively
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Filter $Extension -Recurse |
# Skip directories, because XXXReadMe.txt is a valid directory name
Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
    # For each file
    ForEach-Object {
        # Copy file
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Dst 
    }


# Get file objects recursively
Get-ChildItem -Path $Dst -Filter $Extension -Recurse |
# Skip directories, because XXXReadMe.txt is a valid directory name
Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} 

    ForEach-Object {
        # Add header
       (Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter ",") |
       Select-Object -Skip 1 |
       ConvertFrom-CSV -UseCulture -Header $header | export-csv $_.FullName -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Comment: it looks like your `$Dst` pipeline is missing a `|` after the `Where-Object` call. ///// also, what version of PoSh are you using? the `-File` parameter for `Get-ChildItem` would let you get just files right from the start - but you need ps3+ [i think that is the version it was added].

Comment: The version is 5.1.17134.765. Well, for the moment I can get the files from directory A to directory B and it adds the column header for the first column. The problem is that I have around 500 rows in the csv and would like to have just 3 of them but do not know how to do it. So copy/paste and then removing the rows not needed. I was thinking to get them based on a string written in them.

Comment: so change your GCI call to use `-File`, remove the `Where-Object` section, make sure to pipe the GCI to your `ForEach-Object`, then use `Get-Content` to get the file as _strings_, and finally use `Select-Object` & `-First 4` to get the CSV header & the 1st 3 rows of data.

Comment: Got that. They are not always the first 3. They can be stored anywhere in the csv, mostly slightly before the end of the rows. One time they are rows 175,176,177, other time 455,456,457 and so on.

Comment: you never mentioned that it was three _specific_ rows that vary in location. [*grin*] you need to decide how to choose them via code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. If for example I look at them based on a string let's say the string "item". I want it to get every row that contains the word "item". How would the magic happen then?

Comment: @user11869071 You would probably need to do something like this: [Get Row from CSV File Based On Value](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-get-row-from-csv-file-based-on-value/). `Where` or `Where-Object` would probably be useful to you in trying to select those specific columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this shows one way to get the lines of a file that contain a specified target value. [*grin*] if you still need the header row, that will always be the 1st item in the original collection - `$InStuff[0]` for instance.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4
1, One, Wun, Run
2, Two, Tuu, Item
3, Three, Item, Tree
4, Four, Fo, Pho
5, Item, Five, Phyv
6, Six, Ziks, Psiks
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$TargetValue = 'Item'

$InStuff -match $TargetValue
```

output ...

```
2, Two, Tuu, Item
3, Three, Item, Tree
5, Item, Five, Phyv
```

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me. Thanks for your help.

```
 # Setup source and destination paths
 $Src = 'C:\1From'
 $Dst = 'C:\2To'
 $header = ‘Scan’

 # Wildcard for filter
 $Extension = '*_ALL_Details.csv'

 ######################################################
 ########   Copy files from src to dest folder  #######

 # Get file objects recursively
 Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Filter $Extension -Recurse |
 # Skip directories, because XXXReadMe.txt is a valid directory name
 Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
     # For each file
     ForEach-Object {
         # Copy file
         Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Dst -Force
     }

 ##########################################################
 #######  Add Dest files a header and override csv  #######

 # Get file objects recursively
 Get-ChildItem -Path $Dst -Filter $Extension -Recurse |
 # Skip directories, because XXXReadMe.txt is a valid directory name
 Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
     ForEach-Object {
         # Add header
        (Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter ",") |           
        ConvertFrom-CSV -UseCulture -Header $header | ? Scan -like *Item* | export- 
 csv $_.FullName -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
     }
```